# I get an Error 400 on Google when using the authorization link for my Python Google API programs, including ones I know worked for others

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

I'm working on a code that requires the use of google_auth_oauthlib, but the authorization link that my code produces sends me to a
"400. That’s an error.
The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know."
page.
So I switched tracks and moved to a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQQEaSnQ_bs) and copied the code:

```
    import os
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    import pickle
    
    credentials = None
    
    # token.pickle stores the user's credentials from previously successful logins
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        print('Loading Credentials From File...')
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)
    
    
    # Google's Request
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
    
    
    # If there are no valid credentials available, then either refresh the token or log in.
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            print('Refreshing Access Token...')
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            print('Fetching New Tokens...')
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secrets.json',
                scopes=[
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
                ]
            )
            print("test")
            flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent',
                                  authorization_prompt_message='')
            credentials = flow.credentials
    
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
                print('Saving Credentials for Future Use...')
                pickle.dump(credentials, f)
    
    youtube = build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)
    
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part = "status", playlistId = "UUCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g"
    )
    
    response = request.execute()
    
    print(response)
```

Lo and behold, I still had the same problem despite Corey Schafer, the Youtuber who made the tutorial, having no such issue.
Thing to note: While I get no such issue in Spyder, where I'm running the program, if I run it in cmd or CMD.exe prompt (Opened through Anaconda) I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google_auth_oauthlib' error despite pip installing it. Not sure if this is important or not.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can't use Brave for this because it requires cookies. After switching to Chrome it works fine.

Comment: It didn't work with Firefox (and NoScript and AdBlocker, ...). After swtiching to Chrome it worked.